# How do I find the zeros

Tags: c++

I have been given an assignment to find all the evens, odds, and zeros of a number the user types in. I have figured out almost all the code but I can't figure out why it is not printing out the number of zeros. Can anyone try to explain why this is happening? Thank You.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cmath>
    #include <array>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <ctype.h>
    using namespace std;
    int main() {
        string stringToGuess;
        cout << "Hello user would you please enter a long number." << endl;
        cin >> stringToGuess;
        int arrLength = stringToGuess.length();
        int odd = 0;
        int even = 0;
        int zero = 0;
        char cho;
        char length = stringToGuess.length();
        char arrToGuess[arrLength];
      for (int i = 0; i < arrLength; i++){
        arrToGuess[i] = stringToGuess[i];
      }
      for (int a = 0; a < arrLength; a++){
        if (arrToGuess[a] == 0) {
          zero = zero + 1;
          cout << "ZERO";
        }
        if (arrToGuess[a] != 0 ){  
          if (arrToGuess[a] % 2 == 0) {
            even = even + 1;
            cout << "Even"; 
          }
          if (arrToGuess[a] % 2 != 0){
            odd = odd + 1;
            cout << "Odd";
          }
        }
      }
      cout << "Odd Numbers = " << odd << endl;
      cout << "Even Numbers = " << even - zero << endl;
      cout << "Zeros = " << zero << endl;
      cout << "Total = " << arrLength << " Numbers" << endl;
    }
```

Comment: Sounds like a chance to practice using your debugger!! https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: If the user types in `111`, do `11`, `11`, and `111` count as odds? Are we just looking at individual digits?

Comment: Elements of `arrToGuess` are characters. `'0' != 0`

Comment: we are only looking at idividual digits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't find the zeros because you are actually testing symbols instead of the actual numbers, as your input is a string of text. The symbol `'0'` is actually the code 48 in the ASCII table, so if you test `if (arrToGuess[a] == 0)` it will never be true.

Use `if (arrToGuess[a] == '0')` instead.

The other numbers work because coincidentally, the codes for the odds and even numbers are also odds and evens.

Comment: Keep in mind that, while this will almost never come up, c++ doesn't guarantee that ASCII encoding is used. It does guarantee that the digits are sequential. So by subtracting `'0'` from each digit you will get it's numeric value, regardless of the encoding used.

Answer (score 0):

Igor answered your question.  You need to convert your characters to integer values, e.g. with std::stoi.

Your code works for 1-9 because ascii for odds happen to be odd, and evens happen to be even.  Zero has an even encoding, so I assume you are counting an extra even digit.

Comment: if you only need to look at a digit then `stoi` is overkill

Answer (score 0):

The first problem which arises is that the character 0 is not equal to integer 0

0 != '0'

You should use 48 instead of 0 if you really want this code to work, the rest has been answered by other people. Here's the code if you want your code to work.

A simple replace from 0 to 48 works.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <array>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    string stringToGuess;
    cout << "Hello user would you please enter a long number." << endl;
    cin >> stringToGuess;
    int arrLength = stringToGuess.length();
    int odd = 0;
    int even = 0;
    int zero = 0;
    char cho;
    char length = stringToGuess.length();
    char arrToGuess[arrLength];
  for (int i = 0; i < arrLength; i++){
    arrToGuess[i] = stringToGuess[i];
  }
  for (int a = 0; a < arrLength; a++){
    if (arrToGuess[a] == 48) {
      zero = zero + 1;
      cout << "ZERO";
    }
    if (arrToGuess[a] != 0 ){  
      if (arrToGuess[a] % 2 == 0) {
        even = even + 1;
        cout << "Even"; 
      }
      if (arrToGuess[a] % 2 != 0){
        odd = odd + 1;
        cout << "Odd";
      }
    }
  }
  cout << "Odd Numbers = " << odd << endl;
  cout << "Even Numbers = " << even - zero << endl;
  cout << "Zeros = " << zero << endl;
  cout << "Total = " << arrLength << " Numbers" << endl;
}
```